# How to solve "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" in Windows?

Tags: windows, dll, ldd, nm

I'm facing the following error message:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Application Server Core, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

This means that the file "Application Server Core.dll", version 1.0.0.0, is not present in a runtime directory.
**A** runtime directory?
Yes: I have an application in one directory and a bunch of DLLs in another one. But that's not the main issue.

The point is that I'm working in a *client* environment, which means that the "Application *Server* Core" should even not be loaded.

So, I'm asking which other application or DLL is trying to load this DLL. I can't find out while checking the callstack, so I thought having a look inside the other applications or DLLs, using the Windows equivalent of the `ldd` or the `nm` UNIX/Linux commands, and you can already guess my question:

What are the Windows equivalents for the UNIX/Linux `ldd` and `nm` commands?

Thanks in advance

Comment: dependencywalker.com has such as tool, but it won't work for .NET dependencies (similarly `ldd` and `nm` won't tell you about libraries loaded through `dlopen`)  Dependency Walker does have a "profiling" mode which finds runtime usage of `LoadLibrary` (but you're back to not knowing which code caused it) which unfortunately has major issues when used on .NET programs.

Comment: The Windows SDK also has `dumpbin /imports`, which unlike `Dependency Walker` or `ldd` doesn't actually try to find the dependencies on your system or recursively process their dependencies.  It also won't do anything for `LoadLibrary` runtime dependencies.

Comment: dotPeek or ildasm can show you .NET-style dependencies